# Stored procedure to insert 1st date to the end date of current month

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have been trying to have a crack at this for some time now and I made some progress into figuring out to inserting the rest of the days from today to the end of the month but I'm having no luck to figuring out how to make it so that @start_date selects from the start of the current month. The stored procedure is as follows:

```
    BEGIN 
    SET @start_date = NOW(); 
    SET @end_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY); 
    WHILE(@start_date< @end_date) DO 
        INSERT INTO date (date) VALUES (@start_date); 
        SET @start_date = DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY); 
    END WHILE; 
END
```

I'm hoping to get some explanation as to what is it that I need to replace the NOW() value to to make it so that it dynamically retrieves the start date of the current month? Of course hard coding the date works but since this stored procedure is meant to have a monthly routine, hard coding isn't the best applicable scenario. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! To anyone who's having the same problem or something of the similar sort, here's my solution.

```
BEGIN 
    SET @start_date = DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))-1 DAY); 
    SET @end_date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01');  
    WHILE(@start_date < @end_date) DO 
        INSERT INTO date (date) VALUES (@start_date); 
        SET @start_date = DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY); 
    END WHILE; 
END
```